# sql case returning a multiple unknown string values in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that stores measurements for a forest plot. The table has the following headings:

```
id, plot_id, date, plot_measurement_type_id, value_type_id, value_int, value_real, value_bool, value_char, measurement_units_id
```

It was intended to retain as much flexibility as possible because there will be lots of different types of measurements for the plot over the years and wanted to retain small tables.

plot_measurement_type_id relates to different types of measurements. In the main there is only one measurement per plot for a date. HOWEVER, when measurement_type_id = 5 or 6 this is observations and there can be many. Is there a way to use the case statement (as below) and concatenate all of the observations (e.g. all of the 5's) to put into one column. My work around for this was to use max and min to get the observations into separate tables but this will not work when there are several observations.

I intend to create a view to display the data in a more readable format for a user ...using the following query.

```
select pl.plot_id, 
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 1 then value_real end) slope,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 2 and value_bool = TRUE then 'true' else 'false' end) burnt,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 3 then value_real end) estimated_tree_canopy,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 4 then value_real end) estimated_grass_cover,   
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 5 then value_char end) human_use,   
    min(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 5 then value_char end) human_use2,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 6 then value_char end) observations,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 7 then value_char end) notes, 
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 9 then value_real end) wet_litter_weight,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 11 then value_real end) dry_litter_weight,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 10 then value_real end) wet_grass_weight,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 12 then value_real end) dry_grass_weight,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 13 then value_real end) altitude,
    max(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 14 then value_char end) lcc
from forest.plots pl 
    inner join forest.plot_measurement pm on pm.plot_id = pl.plot_id 
group by pl.plot_id
```

Comment: Since you are working with a **relational** database management system you are much better off with a relational data model. What you are proposing here is.... horrible (for want of a better word) and impossible to maintain or properly use (such as creating queries to analyze the data). If you indeed intend "to retain as much flexibility as possible" you should work on creating a data model that works with simple queries, instead of making ugly queries to fit an impossible data model. Sorry, can't make more of it...

Comment: And to provide a little context: I work with Forest Information Systems for many years and have come across legacy databases that look eerily like what you are proposing. It is just bad practice. Please please please, work on your data model if you love your forest.

Comment: I am using the data model of my predecessor and will make the best of it. thanks for your comments all the same

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In Postgres you can use the `string_agg()` function:

```
string_agg(case when pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 5 then value_char end, ', ') human_use2,
```